# How to highlight a table row with the smallest value in a certain column using javascript

Tags: javascript

Supposed that I have a table like this on a webpage with the `id ='table'`:

```
Name        Age          Money(USD)    DATE
A            19            4          2019-03-11 16:15:35
B            20            0          2019-03-11 16:16:37
C            27            3          2019-03-13 04:15:43
D            34            0          2019-03-13 04:16:57
```

Could you help me find the **FIRST SMALLEST VALUE IN THE MONEY COLUMN**, which is 0 for **B** in the Column1 and **HIGHLIGHT** the whole table row for B, using javascript without using any library and any button onClicking?

Note: I have searched around and just been unlucky enough to find the correct answer to my problem.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:*I just got a piece of javacript like this to get the first smallest value and print it out, but not be able to highlight the whole row with it*

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"), minVal;
    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
      // if its the first row get the value
      if(i === 1){minVal = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML; }
     // test with the other values
     else if(minVal > table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML){
       minVal = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
     }
   }
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = " Minimum Value = "+minVal;
console.log(maxVal);
```

Comment: Hey Phuong. Can you share some code, and/or the *specific* reason you're having trouble with this? Without this information it reads very much like you're asking us to write your code for you. I realize this may not be the case, but you'll need to help us help you first :) Also, what do you mean "without any button onClicking" - what triggers the row to be highlighted? The initial page load?

Comment: We need your HTML.

Comment: Is the table updated by either the user who is viewing it, or some other factor, or is the data present when the page loads readonly? As others have stated, we need some code to best help you find your solution.

Comment: @garryman We need more than just HTML. HTML would only allow us to write a solution from scratch, which is *not* a good answer. We need some JavaScript (or some research in lieu of code).

Comment: @Tyler Roper , sorry but I just added the **UPDATE**. Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks Phuong!

Comment: @Aaron, the table is lively and constantly updated as per the php code retrieves the table in the database.

Comment: @garryman, The HTML is simple as you know. It has only `<table id="table"> <tr> <td> ... </td></tr></table>`.

Answer (score 1):

This simply keeps track of the minimum row, and lets you hang your formatting off of that:

```js
const highlightLowest = () => {
  var rows = table.rows;
  var minRow = rows[0]
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){
     rows[i].classList.remove('highlight')
     if (Number(rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML) < Number(minRow.cells[2].innerHTML)) {
        minRow = rows[i]
     }
  }
  minRow.classList.add('highlight')
}
```

```css
tr.highlight td {background-color: yellow}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr><td>A</td><td>19</td><td>4</td><td>2019-03-11 16:15:35</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td><td>20</td><td>0</td><td>2019-03-11 16:16:37</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td><td>27</td><td>3</td><td>2019-03-13 04:15:43</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td><td>34</td><td>0</td><td>2019-03-13 04:16:57</td></tr>
</table>

<hr />

<button onClick="highlightLowest()">Highlight</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"), minVal, minI;
for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
   if(i === 1){
      minVal = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
   }
   else if(minVal > table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML){
      minVal = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
      minI = i;
   }
}
table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<span style="background:red">' + table.rows[minI].cells[2].innerHTML + '</span>';
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var minVal = undefined;
for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
{
    if(i === 1){
        minVal = table.rows[i].cells[2]; 
    }
    else if(minVal.innerHTML > table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML){   
        minVal = table.rows[i].cells[2];
    }
}

minVal.parentElement.style.background="yellow";
```

Comment: Excellent. This works for me now. You are so fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do:

- Convert `innerHTML` to a number using `+`
- Keep track of the **row number** while looping.

This is the code

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"), minVal;
let minRow = 1;
    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
      // if its the first row get the value
      if(i === 1){
          minVal = +table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;

      }
     // test with the other values
     else if(minVal > table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML){
       minVal = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
       minRow = i; 
     }
   }

let row = table.rows[minRow];
row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The function 'highlight' takes the column that you want to base your highlighting upon as an argument.

```js
// Get your table's headers    
headers = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody tr th')

// Get your table's headers 
rows = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody tr')

// Declaring function that takes wanted column as argument
highlight = (colName) =>{
let min = 0;
for(i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
 if(headers[i].innerText == colName){
  for(j=1;j<rows.length;j++){
      value = parseInt(rows[j].children[i].innerHTML);
        if(j == 1){
          min = value;
}
        if(value < min){
          rows[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
          break;
}
     

      
}
}
}
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Test 1</th>
    <th>Test 2</th>
    <th>Test 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>89</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<input type='text' id='col'>
<button onclick=highlight(document.getElementById('col').value)>Highlight based on input column</button>
```